# Override, extend or roll your own HttpException?

Tags: c#, asp.net, httpexception

I want to have control over my Http Exceptions to the point of being able to dictate what is in the body of the response. If I throw a standard `HttpException(404, "not found");` then using fiddler I can see the 404 status code is set but there is all this garbage html thats shoved into the response body.

Is there any way to override or extend the HttpException class to allow you to inject your own content into the response body?

I have attempted to implement my own `CustomHttpException` that like the HttpException extends the ExternalException class but no matter how I cut it the system always throws a 500 error with the same standard html in the body.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, no, no.

Take a look at [CustomErrors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h0hfz6fc.aspx).

Basically you do something like this

```
    <customErrors defaultRedirect="GenericError.htm"
                  mode="RemoteOnly">
       <error statusCode="404"
              redirect="NotFound.aspx"/>
    </customErrors>
```

Comment: Thats going on the assumption that I'm returning a user friendly html page to a browser. How do I deal with ajax calls?

Comment: Not really, you can redirect errors do dynamic .aspx urls, where you can manipulate resulting content in code-behind. Are you using asp.net webforms or asp.net-mvc?

Comment: MVC 3, I want a discreet Rest service that can return proper http status codes and either json or xml to be consumed by the browser/ajax/mobile app etc.

Comment: You can derive from [HandleErrorAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.handleerrorattribute.aspx) and control resulting content then.